# Colocar texto ao lado de imagem

Tags: html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando colocar uma imagem e um texto do lado, mas não estou conseguindo. O texto fica embaixo da foto ou eu consigo colocar a primeira frase do texto no mesmo nível que o topo da imagem da esquerda.

Tentei usar o `display:block`, até certo ponto funciona, porquê fica do lado da imagem, mas fica como coluna.

Não fica igual o da imagem acima, com o texto embaixo da foto.

```
<div>

   <img width="186" height="186" />
   Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.

</div>
```

Minha estrutura é igual a essa acima.
A imagem tem **186px** de largura.

Sem CSS, só HTML achei que funcionava.

Exemplo:

http://jsfiddle.net/9r3d8hs2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Veja se é isso que você quer:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img  width="300" height="150" src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/dioLI.png'/></td>
    
    <td> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </br>
Phasellus bibendum aliquet erat, ut ornare purus malesuada et.</td> 
  </tr>
 
</table>
```

Comment: É isso mesmo. Mas sem `table`, pelo amor de Deus. Rsrs. Mas acho que já consegui aqui...

Answer (score 7):

Você deve colocar a imagem dentro de um `<p>`/`<div>` e usar um elemento `align` na tag `<img>`.

Ficaria assim:

```
<div>
   <img align="left">
   Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

Comment: Se quiser, pode trocar o left por right, middle, top ou bottom. Mais que isso, só pelo CSS

Comment: E como eu dou espaço no texto ? Porquê está grudado. http://jsfiddle.net/9r3d8hs2/

Comment: Uma observação: `align` não é suportado no HTML5, se estiver usando uma versão anterior está ok.

Comment: Ajusta um margin-right e margin-bottom pra img no CSS que resolve

Comment: Ou adiciona com elemento style, se for só pra uma imagem

Comment: Bem lembrado @renan, se for HTML5 só com `position`

Comment: -1, Não utilize, como descrito pelo @renan, o align não é suportado em HTML5 e num futuro não muito distante pode não haver mais suporte para o atributo.

Comment: @DorivalZanetto mas a resposta não está errada, vai depender do tipo de documento que o AP está desenvolvendo. Se não for HTML5, não tem problema em usar `align`.

Answer (score 7):

Consegui, fiz dessa forma.

Coloquei essa propriedade na imagem e funcionou.

```
img.face{
    float: left;
    border: transparent thin solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0;
    max-width: 186px;
}
```

Comment: Na verdade me deu um branco feio... isso é muito básico.